# Change "enter" key text on iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, forms, safari

(This question concerns HTML pages in Safari, not app development in XCode.)

In Safari on iPhone, when clicking on a `<input>` or `<textarea>`, the text on the enter key 
says "enter".

Is it possible to change this text?

I remember a posting saying something about using `<textarea title="My button text">`, but this does not work when I tried it.

Comment: Not the return button text, but you can change the keyboard slightly: See http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html

Comment: Interesting. Can I have "Send" as button text, or is "Go" the only alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note.**

You get the return key and keyboard types defined in the OS. Unless you want to try to hack the keyboard's view hierarchy to change that button, which would be a really bad plan. (Standard recommendation here is to file a bug report with Apple to let them know you'd like more/different options.)