# HTML5 when open keyboard on ios brower, change return to 'done' or 'send'

Tags: html

```
<form action="return true">
   <input type="search" />
</form>
```

I know how to do `search` and `go`, but how to change this word to others like 'done' or 'send'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go vs. return button in iOS keyboard for HTML input forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986347/go-vs-return-button-in-ios-keyboard-for-html-input-forms)

Comment: Also, look at this [Change “enter” key text on iPhone keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349371/change-enter-key-text-on-iphone-keyboard)